# query explode multiple values in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need your help. I have 2 table.

**1.company_classifications**

```
company_name-classifications

Company A-1,2,3

Company B-1,2
```

**2.classifications**

```
id-name

1-Music 

2-Technologi

3-Food
```

**I need query for result like this :**

```
company_name-classification_name

Company A-Music, Technologi, Food   

Company B-Music, Food
```

Comment: See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

Comment: If you have multiple values in one column for one row, you need to normalise your database. However, you need to work on your question before I can read it and help you.

Comment: @eggyal, er yes (I know you know that).

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET()` can help you on this but normalization is the best way to do.

Comment: @eggyal,@Jodrell Ya, i know that. but the structure values i have from my client.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form, the concept was formalised by Codd in 1971 but still ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select cc.company_name,group_concat(c.name)
from company_classifications cc 
inner join classifications c 
on c.id = find_in_set(c.id,cc.classifications)
group by cc.company_name;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/426f0/15)